# WHERE value in the text field is higher than a number

Tags: mysql

I have no idea how to solve this, so I hope you can give me some hints.

I've created a text column in mysql, let's say it's called "values". In this column I've got something like this

```
| value1 = number1
| value2 = text2
| value3 = text3
```

It's all in one text field. So i want to search through it, but I want to do this like that: to find all the rows with value1 is higher than 100 (so the number1 is for example 101). How to do that? I've tried some experiments with "LIKE" but it only helps me when i want to find a specific number, not the higher/lower numbers.

Please let me know what you think, happy new year!

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT  * FROM table
WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX(values,' ',1)) = 'value1'
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(values,' ',-1) > somenumber
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84468/6)

BUT,in the long run [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is more useful.